# VBA copy column's value to another column

Tags: excel, copy, vba

how to use VBA's End(xlRight) to copy one column's value to another one?
like I want to always copy columnZ's range("Z4:Z203") value to another column's range("i5:i204"),how can i use End(xlright) check if the column was pasted and it will paste on next column ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply copy always the needed range?

```
Sub test()
Range("Z4:Z203").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I5:I204").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```